# Java annotation processing only

Tags: java, annotations, javac, compile-time, annotation-processing

I'm working on annotation-processing from within java code. I've already figured out how to use Java Compiler API, (`JavaCompiler`, `CompilationTask`, etc.)

All this aforementioned stuff compiles class. 
Is there a way to run annotation processing without compilation?

I've got some idea to implement some so-called "StopProcessor" which will always fail and stop compilation process. Is there any other solution?

Comment: "without compilation" means ? How you are using a java class without compile? what is use case ?

Comment: @NaveenRamawat I mean I need process annotations and stop. I don't need to generate bytecode.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Seb I'm trying to process annotations let's say 100 times in a row and then collect results, I don't need to actually compile source into the bytecode

Comment: @Dany So you want to perform some kind of static code-checks before the actual compilation? You could achieve this by e.g. using antlr to generate the AST of your program and performing your preprocessing on the AST; but this is probably not the solution you are looking for...

Comment: @Seb yeah man, you got me, static type checks. They are already implemented as annotations processors

Comment: I would start by looking at the _proc:only_ [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) option to see what that does and whether it's available via code.

Comment: Have you tried to passing "-proc:only" as option [api.javax.tools.JavaCompiler.getTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask-java.io.Writer-javax.tools.JavaFileManager-javax.tools.DiagnosticListener-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) (options parameter)

Comment: @McDowell I tried one minute ago and it worked! Thank you, I didn't know this option, guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass "-proc:only" argument to the java compiler. Here is an excerpt from [the javac tool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html):

```
-proc:only means that only annotation processing is done, without any subsequent compilation.
```